# Supernova Emoji library integration with socket.io chat app in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, socket.io, emoji

I am making chat app in android through socket.io which includes recylerview/adapter & model class. I have also successfully added emoji library separately but i want to add emoji library & recyclerview on same activity. Can you guide me about how can I do it on same page(activity). Responses will be highly appreciated.

I am following these guides.

https://github.com/hani-momanii/SuperNova-Emoji

https://dev.to/medaymentn/creating-a-realtime-chat-app-with-android--nodejs-and-socketio-4o55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Layout File for your Chat View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/contentRoot1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorchatbg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentRoot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@color/voilacabs">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_back_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_15"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_15">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout_back_arrow"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_username"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Username"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_typing"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Typing..."
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="4dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@drawable/shadow_top" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonEmoji"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/chat_smilly" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonEmoji"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconEditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:emojiconSize="28sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lauout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTextMessage"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/buttonMessage"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/chat_send" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>




        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Your Activity Code is like

```
private EmojIconActions emojIcon;

edMessage = (EmojiconEditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
btEmoji = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonEmoji);

emojIcon = new EmojIconActions(this, contentRoot, edMessage, btEmoji);
                emojIcon.ShowEmojIcon();
```

Comment: Class referenced in the layout file, hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconEditText, was not found in the project or the libraries 
The Android Studio is  giving this error: